# android studio The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

how to solve **The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported**

in android studio

how to solve **The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported**

in android studio gradle.plugin.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported. See below for more detailed information.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration?hl=en